# How to escape utf-8 and convert utf-8 code to bytes

Tags: c, string, utf-8

I need to convert string (char[]) to string with unicode escape (in format: \u0105). I write unicode code to convert string from file example:

"ąćżźóÓŻŹĆĄŚś ƐƑ ƁƂ ЁЂ" => "\u0105\u0107\u017C\u017A\u00F3\u00D3\u017B\u0179\u0106\u0104\u015A\u015B \u0190\u0191 \u0181\u0182 \u0401\u0402".

Now i need write reverse so for example: "\u0105" => "ą" (char[] = {0xC4, 0x85}).

How do this (using only C)?
Let's say i have utf-8 code in `uint32_t code = 0x0105;`

Here my code to convert string to unicode escape:

```
static const uint32_t unicode[48] = {
    0x0000, 0x0040, 0x0080, 0x00C0, 0x0100, 0x0140, 0x0180, 0x01C0, 0x0200, 0x0240, 0x0280, 0x02C0, 0x0300, 0x0340, 0x0380, 0x03C0, 
    0x0400, 0x0440, 0x0480, 0x04C0, 0x0500, 0x0540, 0x0580, 0x05C0, 0x0600, 0x0640, 0x0680, 0x06C0, 0x0700, 0x0740, 0x0780, 0x07C0, 
    0x0800, 0x1000, 0x2000, 0x3000, 0x4000, 0x5000, 0x6000, 0x7000, 0x8000, 0x9000, 0xA000, 0xB000, 0xC000, 0xD000, 0xE000, 0xF000, 
};

...

    FILE* fh = fopen("utf.txt", "r");
    char* result;
    char* tmpMemoryBuffer;
    size_t currentSize = 255, currentIndex = 0;
    result = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * currentSize);
    memset(result, 0, sizeof(char) * currentSize);


    if (fh != NULL)
    {
        uint8_t c2, c = (uint8_t) getc(fh);
        uint32_t tmp = 0;

        while (c != EOF && c != 0xFF)
        {
            if ((currentIndex - 1) == currentSize)
            {
                tmpMemoryBuffer = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * currentSize);
                memcpy(tmpMemoryBuffer, result, sizeof(char) * currentSize);
                result = (char*) realloc(result, sizeof(char) * (currentSize + 255));
                memcpy(result, tmpMemoryBuffer, sizeof(char) * currentSize);
                currentSize += 255;
            }

            if (c >= 0x20 && c <= 0x7E)
            {
                //Is normal char
                printf("Normal:\t%c\n", c);
                result[currentIndex++] = (char) c;
            }
            else if (c >= 0xC0 && c <= 0xEF && (c2 = (uint8_t) getc(fh)) != EOF)
            {
                //Is unicode
                c &= 0x3F;
                c2 &= 0x7F;
                tmp = unicode[c];
                tmp += c2;
                sprintf(result + currentIndex, "\\u%04X", tmp);
                currentIndex += 6;
                printf("Unicode:\t%04X\n", tmp);

            }
            else
            {
                printf("Wrong format for 0x%X\n", c);
                break;
            }
            c = (uint8_t) getc(fh);
        }

        result[currentIndex] = '\0';
        fclose(fh);
...
        free(result);
```

There is some better way to do this?

Comment: UTF-8 is a *byte* encoding. If you have a collection of UTF-8 encoded characters, they're already in bytes.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude In utf-8 i have 0x0105, in bytes: {0xC4, 0x85}, this is not a same.

Comment: Don't confuse a Unicode codepoint with a particular representation of said codepoint like utf-8.

Comment: Anyways, encoding a code point (usually stored as a 32 bit int) to bytes as utf-8 and back is pretty simple but tedious. I think it's easier to use a library like ICU or libunistring. You can also use the standard functions like `c32rtomb()` with an appropriate locale.

Comment: @Shawn I would like use this in embadded, `c32rtomb` is light enought?

Comment: For embedded you'll probably have to do it yourself or snag existing code.

Comment: `"\u0105\u0107\u017C\u017A\u00F3\u00D3\u017B\u0179\u0106\u0104\u015A\u015B \u0190\u0191 \u0181\u0182 \u0401\u0402"` (with quotes in the file) is a valid JSON representation for the string you want. Perhaps a JSON decoder would be appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If any will search i write this as continuation of code in question:

`char result[] = "\u0105\u0107\u017C\u017A\u00F3";`

```
char* resultStr = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * currentIndex + 1);
size_t reIndex = 0;

for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(result); i++) 
{
    if (result[i] == '\\')
    {
        if (result[i + 1] != '\0')
        {
            i++;
            switch (result[i])
            {
                case 'u':
                    if (result[i + 1] != '\0' && result[i + 2] != '\0' && result[i + 3] != '\0' && result[i + 4] != '\0')
                    {
                        const char hexstring[5] = {result[i + 1], result[i + 2], result[i + 3], result[i + 4], '\0'};
                        uint32_t code = (uint32_t)strtol(hexstring, NULL, 16);
                        printf ("Code = 0x%X\n", code);
                        uint8_t firstByte = 47;
                        uint8_t secondByte = 0;

                        for (size_t i = 1; i < 48; i++)
                        {
                            if (unicode[i] > code)
                            {
                                firstByte = i - 1;
                                secondByte = (uint8_t)(code - unicode[i - 1]);
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        firstByte |= 0xC0;
                        secondByte |= 0x80;
                        resultStr[reIndex++] = (char)firstByte;
                        resultStr[reIndex++] = (char)secondByte;
                        i += 4;
                    }
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //Error
        }
    }
    else
    {
        resultStr[reIndex++] = result[i];
    }
}

resultStr[reIndex] = '\0';
printf("Result = %s\n", resultStr);
```

This require refactor and add some features like handle '\n', '\t', '\r', but is light and fast.

Anyone have better ideas?